# Why isn't Robin Williams in Sean's military photo?

Tags: realism, props, good-will-hunting

In [*Good Will Hunting (1997)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/) during the scene where Will and Sean have their first session, Will notices a photo of Sean and his buddies in Vietnam. The photo is shown below. My question is why Robin Williams is not in the photo? It is typical for historical photos in films to use the actual actors but these men are clearly not Robin Williams. So which one is Sean? And why not use Robin Williams to make it obvious?

[image]

Comment: Robin Williams was the radio moderator they were listening to.

Comment: @BestGuess: Are you referring to [Good Morning, Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_Morning,_Vietnam) ?

Comment: maybe he took the photo?

Comment: @NiceOrc good point, I actually hadn't considered that.